# Laravel i will get integer in DB query

Tags: laravel

after returning $query from this:

```
$query = DB::table('pets')->select('id')->where('id', '=', $pet->id)->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->get();
```

for example i get this result : [{"id":"66"}]
how can i get only 66 as integer?
Thanks!

Comment: Use pluck feature of laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `get()` which returns the entire collection of selected data, use `value('id')` to get the first value of the `id` field.  You also wouldn't need `select('id')` if you use this method.